# How can i make a Mirror for RHEL 6 and 7 Repositories using Amazon ec2 Image

Tags: redhat, yum, spacewalk

Since spacewalk does not support Red Hat Enterprise Linux is it possible to use Amazon Linux AMI ( which supports RHEL yum updates ) and use that as a proxy or mirror to re-distribute yum updates? or use Pulp/Katello for RHEL update distribution. There is no information i could find in my google search.

Here is some info i have gathered:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/
2. https://www.theforeman.org/introduction.html
3. https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/blob/master/scripts/clone-errata/rhn-clone-errata.py
4. https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/5i65rb/creating_rhel_7_repository_mirror/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that Spacewalk does not connect to RHEL repos (otherwise it would compete with Satellite), you can get around it using mrepo to mirror the repos and then upload into Spacewalk.  It doesn't get errata, but there is a python script called get-errata.py ( I believe) that will do this for you.  They require a little bit of setup,but they work.  I know because I used both these tools to maintain the patch (and install) infrastructures of a couple different companies.

Just search for mrepo (plenty of pages and examples).  get-errata.py will be a little more work.

Comment: mrepo seems to be old with Latest commit on Jul 4, 2015. Would i still require a redhat subscription ? from your experience. BTW, i also found https://github.com/dtmateojr/dtmrepo, any opinion on that ?

Comment: dtmrepo looks good, you could try that.  Yes, you still need a redhat subscription.  They won't let you connect without one.  The mrepo configuration process has you configure the subscription information for it.